# Using jQuery to gather data from HTML attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to put together a web form to mark an indeterminate number of employees as either present or absent. The page itself contains an arbitrary number of divs of the form:

```
<div class="employee" empID="9" presence="0">
```

The divs themselves contain the options, with 'presence' being changed to 1 or 2 using jQuery depending on the option selected.

When the 'submit' button is pressed, I'd like to convert this data into a parsable array of pairs of 'empID' and 'presence'. I've tried doing this with jQuery as follows:

```
$('.cic-button').click(function(){
        var submitData = {employees:[]};
        $('firedrill-employee').each(function(){
            submitData.push({
                employeeID: $(this).attr('empID'),
                presence: $(this).attr('presence')
            });
        });
    });
```

However, when this is done, the submitData variable is failing to populate. Any idea why? Am I going about this in the correct manner? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend not making up random attributes but instead using HTML5's custom data attributes. Ex: `<div class="employee" data-empid="9" data-presence="0">`

Comment: What is `$('firedrill-employee')`? There's no such HTML tag. If that's supposed to be a class, you need `.` at the beginning.

Comment: do you mean submitData.employees.push() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few errors. Make the class that you iterate over the collection of "`employee`" not "`firedrill-employee`" and don't forget the dot to indicate it's a class. Reference the `employees` array withing the `submitData` object. You can't just `push` an element into an object.

```
$('.cic-button').click(function () {
    var submitData = {
        employees: []
    };
    $('.employee').each(function () {
        submitData.employees.push({
            employeeID: $(this).data('empID'),
            presence: $(this).data('presence')
        });
    });
    console.log(submitData);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsbin.com/kaviwirave/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the employee array as such:

```
$('.cic-button').click(function(){
    var submitData = {employees:[]}; // employees is an array within submitData...
    $('.firedrill-employee').each(function(){
        submitData.employees.push({ // ...so amend code here to push to the array, not submitData
            employeeID: $(this).attr('empID'),
            presence: $(this).attr('presence')
        });
    });
    console.log(submitData);    
});
```

See example JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yng1qb6o/

Comment: what does `specify the employee array as such` mean? Seems like all you did was fix a syntax error ... but didn't say that

Comment: It seems to me, that he need to loop `$('.employee')`, not `$('.firedrill-employee')` (according to the question and the code he posted)

Comment: @charlietfl - The original code attempted to push to an object (`submitData`), not an array (`submitData.employees`).

Comment: @phillip100 - Original code used a selector for `firedrill-employee`, I assume the HTML provided in the question was just an example so I kept the selector in his JS.

Comment: so instead of expecting people to be code diff tools, a simple explanation would help. Not a big deal but not always easy to spot differences

Comment: Done, commented in. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

**[Js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mmoowz9/3/)**

```
$('.cic-button').click(function () {

    var submitData = [];

    $('.employee').each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        // Create and obj 
        var obj = new Object(); // {};
        obj["employeeID"] = self.attr("empID");
        obj["presence"] = self.attr("presence");

        //push that object into an array
        submitData.push(obj);

        console.log(obj);
        console.log(submitData);
    });
});
```